# How to compile ZeroMQ 4.1.0 without gssapi?

Tags: zeromq

I would like to compile zeromq statically without gssapi, because I don't have any need for security at the zmq level.

Is is possible to remove gssapi from zmq, so that it doesn't get into `lib` file via some switch or a flag?

Answer (score 1):

there is probably some option to the configure script but you can definitely go into the platform.hpp file and remove or comment out the following line:

```
#define HAVE_LIBGSSAPI_KRB5 1
```